# How to calculate on client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

Work on **C# asp.net**. My **gridview** has five columns. Input on my Quantity column need to calculate the Item Total and Total column value.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bind the event `onkeyup` in quantity `Textbox` that triggers a `javascript` function from where you can calculate and enter the value in `Item Total` column.

You can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to ease your task.

Could you please show some code that you have done so far?

Comment: thanks,for the idea .I have already done ,way to calculation on ItemTotal.will you plz give me some idea or syntax how to calculate Total value?

Comment: may i know how you have generated the gridview and what is your client side script till now ?